# How to get out of Recursive function?

Tags: javascript

I wrote this function to find a particular element in a table :

```
function LoopThroughChildElements(parantEle,flag) {
    for (var i = 0; i < parantEle.childNodes.length; i++) {
        if (parantEle.childNodes[i].childNodes.length > 0) {
             LoopThroughChildElements(parantEle.childNodes[i]);
        }
        else {
            if (parantEle.childNodes[i].id.indexOf("chkSelect") > 0) {
                 alert("Found");  
                 return parantEle.childNodes[i];
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

When executing this:

```
 var checkBox = LoopThroughChildElements(col);
 alert(checkBox);
```

I get an alert of `"Found"`, but the result stays null all time ..

Why does this happen? How to break the recursion loop when I get my result?

Comment: is the leftover "}" at the end of your first code block relevant?

Answer (score 3):

Your `return` only returns the element up one level in your recursive call - you need to make sure it gets returned all the way to the top.

You thus need to replace your line

```
LoopThroughChildElements(parantEle.childNodes[i]);
```

(which is currently discarding the returned element) with something like

```
var rtn = LoopThroughChildElements(parantEle.childNodes[i]);
if (rtn != null)
    return rtn;
```